# I'm getting a [json.exception.type_error.302] for some reason in my code. I know what the error means but I don't know where there's a fault

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

My code goes through the values of each sample in a JSON file and gives out the number of sorting comparisons, the amount of memory, and time it takes for the sorting to happen. But for some reason the code is throwing me an error. Would love it if someone could help me out.
I'm getting a [json.exception.type_error.302] for some reason in my code. I know what the error means but I don't know where there's a fault

To be exact, this is the error I'm getting - "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type nlohmann::detail::type_error: [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be number, but is null"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "json.hpp"
#include "mergesort.h"
#include "insertionsort.h"
#include "quicksort.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::ifstream file;
  file.open(argv[1]);
  nlohmann::json jsonObject;
  if (file.is_open()) {
    file >> jsonObject;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Invalid Argument" << std::endl;
  }

  clock_t mergeTime, quickTime, insertTime;
  extern int insertMemAccesses, insertCompare, mergeMemAccesses, mergeCompare, quickCompare, quickMemAccesses;
//    std::cout << jsonObject;
//    nlohmann::json jsonOutput;

  std::cout << "Sample,InsertSortTime,InsertionSortCompares,InsertionSortMemaccess,MergeSortCompares,MergeSortMemaccess,QuickSortTime,QuickSortCompares,QuickSortMemaccess";

  int arraysize = jsonObject["metadata"]["arraySize"];
  int numsamples = jsonObject["metadata"]["numSamples"];


  for (int i = 0; i <= numsamples; i++) {
    std::string sample;
    if (i < 9) {
      sample = "Sample0" + std::to_string(i+1);
    } else {
      sample = "Sample" + std::to_string(i+1);
    }

    std::vector<int> insertion;
    std::vector<int> merge;
    std::vector<int> quick;

    for(int j = 0; j <= arraysize; j++){
      insertion.push_back(jsonObject[sample][j]);
      merge.push_back(jsonObject[sample][j]);
      quick.push_back(jsonObject[sample][j]);
    }

    insertTime = clock();
    InsertionSort(&insertion);
    insertTime = clock() - insertTime;

    insertTime = ((unsigned long)insertTime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    mergeTime = clock();
    MergeSort(&merge);
    mergeTime = clock() - mergeTime;

    mergeTime = ((unsigned long)mergeTime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    quickTime = clock();
    QuickSort(&quick);
    quickTime = clock() - quickTime;

    quickTime = ((unsigned long)quickTime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    std::cout<<sample<<",";
    printf("%.6lu,%d,%d,%.6lu,%d,%d,%.6lu,%d,%d\n",insertTime,insertCompare,insertMemAccesses,mergeTime,mergeCompare,mergeMemAccesses,quickTime,quickCompare,quickMemAccesses);


    insertCompare = 0;
    insertMemAccesses = 0;
    mergeCompare = 0;
    mergeMemAccesses = 0;
    quickCompare = 0;
    quickMemAccesses = 0;

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: debugger gives you any additional information about the line?

Comment: At the very least you need to use your debugger to determine where the exception is thrown for, and provide the input file that results in the thrown exception. It is not possible to determine anything else without this information. You do know how to use a debugger, right? Because knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer?

Comment: The debugger just seems to be saying that the function requires integers but my function specifically needs a vector as an argument so I don't see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step through the code, and which line does the exception happen on? If you don't have a way to step through, then add in some `std::cerr` calls throughout to see where it is failing. I would assume that the error occurs on one of the `push_back` lines, most likely the first. You have `j <= arraysize`, which most likely goes out of bounds, so when you try to access `jsonObject[sample][arraysize]` this causes the error.

Also, you could probably just do `quick = merge = insertion = jsonObject[sample].get<std::vector<int>>()`, instead of needing the loop